# How to Export current formatted time from several time zones to text file

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, format, timezone

I have little Python programming experience, but need to export the current time in a certain 12-hour format from several different time zones to a single text file.    I have found several solutions, but need to integrate all **three** components into one solution.

```
from datetime import datetime
"{:%A, %B %d %Y %I:%M:%S %p %Z}".format(datetime.now())

import datetime
import pytz
my_date = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('UTC'))
print(my_date)
my_date = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('America/New_York'))
print(my_date)
my_date = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('EST'))
print(my_date)
my_date = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Pacific/Port_Moresby'))
print(my_date)

import datetime
open("C:\temp\current_time.txt", "w").write("UTC Time: ")
open("C:\temp\current_time.txt", "a").write(datetime.datetime.now().ctime()+ '\n')
open("C:\temp\current_time.txt", "a").write("EST Time: ")
open("C:\temp\current_time.txt", "a").write(datetime.datetime.now().ctime()+ '\n')
open("C:\temp\current_time.txt", "a").write("New York Time: ")
open("C:\temp\current_time.txt", "a").write(datetime.datetime.now().ctime()+ '\n')
open("C:\temp\current_time.txt", "a").write("Port Moresby Time: ")
open("C:\temp\current_time.txt", "a").write(datetime.datetime.now().ctime())
```

The last sequence doesn't seem to work in Python 3.7, but if possible would like it to work using (unfortunately) a Python 2.7 installation.

Ultimately, I'd like these results:

```
UTC Time: Monday, October 11, 2021 09:05:17
EST Time: Monday, October 11, 2021 04:05:17 AM
New York Time: Monday, October 11, 2021 05:05:17 AM
Port Moresby Time: Monday, October 11, 2021 07:05:17 PM
```

Much thanks for any assistance.

Comment: note that `%Z` doesn't give you a [time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) but only an abbreviation (which can be kind of useless since ambiguous).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

1. You are calling `datetime.datetime.now` four times which will give you the date-times at the moments when those statements will be executed i.e. you will get date-times at four different moments. You need to get the date-time at the current moment only once and then convert the same to the corresponding date-time in the required timezones.
2. I recommend you use `with open(...) as variable` block which enables your code to close the file automatically as soon as exiting from the block.

**Working code tested using Python 3.9:**

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

now = datetime.now()

now_utc = now.astimezone(pytz.timezone('UTC'))
now_est = now.astimezone(pytz.timezone('EST'))
now_new_york = now.astimezone(pytz.timezone('America/New_York'))
now_port_moresby = now.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Pacific/Port_Moresby'))

format = "%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p"

with open("current_time.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(f'UTC Time: {now_utc.strftime(format)}\n')
    file.write(f'EST Time: {now_est.strftime(format)}\n')
    file.write(f'New York Time: {now_new_york.strftime(format)}\n')
    file.write(f'Port Moresby Time: {now_port_moresby.strftime(format)}\n')
```

**Data written in current_time.txt from a sample run:**

```
UTC Time: Monday, October 11, 2021 12:25:50 PM
EST Time: Monday, October 11, 2021 07:25:50 AM
New York Time: Monday, October 11, 2021 08:25:50 AM
Port Moresby Time: Monday, October 11, 2021 10:25:50 PM
```

**Working code tested using Python 2.7**:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

now_utc = datetime.utcnow()

tz_utc = pytz.timezone('UTC')

now_est = tz_utc.localize(now_utc).astimezone(pytz.timezone('EST'))
now_new_york = tz_utc.localize(now_utc).astimezone(pytz.timezone('America/New_York'))
now_port_moresby = tz_utc.localize(now_utc).astimezone(pytz.timezone('Pacific/Port_Moresby'))

format = "%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p"

with open("current_time.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write('UTC Time: ' + now_utc.strftime(format) + '\n')
    file.write('EST Time: ' + now_est.strftime(format) + '\n')
    file.write('New York Time: '+ now_new_york.strftime(format) + '\n')
    file.write('Port Moresby Time: ' + now_port_moresby.strftime(format) + '\n')
```

Comment: btw. [EST is obsolete](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/0bf5a761f6d17840c4a719156e7887d48592647e/northamerica#L188)

Comment: While testing your answer the 'now_utc = now.astimezone(pytz.timezone('UTC'))' line produces: Runtime error/Traceback (most recent call last):/  File "<striing>", line 1, in <module>/ValueError: astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime

Comment: Also, will 'America/New York' automatically adjust between 'Eastern Standard Time' and 'Eastern Daylight Time'?  Much thanks.

Comment: @noni - In your question, you have written, *The last sequence doesn't seem to work in Python 3.7*. This statement confused me about the required version. Now, I've added code for Python 2.7 as well.

Comment: My apologies for not initially clarifying which Python version my installation used.  I tested your code on the installation and all seemed to work to a point.   I changed "current_time.txt" to "c:\temp\current_time.txt" and ended the command with a carriage return, but got a 'Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 2)', plus didn't find the resulting text file.  Much thanks for your expertise.

Comment: One additional important note I should have included is that the time zone of the installation is '(UTC) Coordinated Universal Time'.   Sorry.

Comment: @noni - I had executed the Python 2.7 code using PyCharm. However, when I tried to execute it on the terminal window (command prompt), I too encountered a syntax error. I've updated the code and now it runs on the terminal window successfully and also produces current_time.txt with the desired content. Feel free to comment in case of any further issues or doubts.

Comment: Much thanks for your time and expert code (and the Stackoverflow community allowing for such an exchange). I installed Python 3.9.7 locally and tested your Python 3.9 code (thanks for also including that!).  Curiously, it output 48/47/52/57 to the terminal, but also output the text file.

Comment: @noni - Great to know that you have successfully executed the two programs with the respective versions. Regarding the output 48/47/52/57 to the terminal: please check if you have put some print statements for debugging/testing. If not, you might have unknowingly installed also some plugin(s) at the time of installing python. After writing and executing another program, you should be able to find it out.